# Headphones not working on Alienware 17R2

Tags: sound, 15.04, alsa, headphones, alienware

I have an alienware 17 r2 with Ubuntu 15.04 installed. I have most drivers working however I can't seem to get an audio from headphones when I plug them in. The sound always seems to play only with the laptop speakers whether the headphones are plugged in or not. I don't see any notification or pop-up either if the headphones are plugged in or not.

In the sound settings, under output I only see `Digital Output (S/PDIF)` and `Speakers` but never headphones whether plugged in or not. Even in the alsamixer interface, I don't see headphones volume option.

Does anyone face a similar issue as this or has any idea how to get this working? Im struggling with this for several weeks now to no avail. Please let me know what additional info I may provide to help solve this issue. Thanks in advance!